# Discord user roles are undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I added this new command in my bot, when members execute the command `;;time`, the bot goes through the roles and gives them the claim time. I have given my code along with the error. Any possible solution to fix the error?

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'time',
  description: 'claim time for a user',
  execute(message, args){
    
    let winner;

    if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
      winner = message.mentions.members.first();

    } else {
      winner = message.author;
    }
    
    var time = 0;

    const allowedRole = (winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・booster") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・mvp+・") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・donator") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・mvp・") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・supporter") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・vip+・") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・vip・"));

    if (!allowedRole) {
      message.channel.send('Your total claim time : **10 seconds**!')
      return;
    }

    switch (allowedRole.name) {
      
      case "・vip・":
      time = 12000;

      break;

      case "・vip+・":
      time = 14000;

      break;

      case "・supporter":
      time = 15000;

      break;

      case "・mvp・":
      time = 19000;

      break;

      case "・donator":
      time = 20000;

      break;

      case "・mvp+・":
      time = 22000;

      break;

      case "・booster":
      time = 900000;

      break;

    }
    if (time === 900000) {
      message.channel.send('Your total claim time is : **15 Minutes**!')
    } else {
    message.channel.send(`Your total claim time is : **${time / 1000} seconds**!`)
    }

  }
}
```

And here is the error :

```
/home/runner/New-Night/commands/second.js:15
    const allowedRole = (winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・booster") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・mvp+・") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・donator") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・mvp・") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・supporter") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・vip+・") || winner.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "・vip・"));
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/New-Night/commands/second.js:15:39)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/New-Night/index.js:72:33)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/New-Night/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/New-Night/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/New-Night/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/New-Night/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/New-Night/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/New-Night/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
```

I searched on google and stack overflow for answers but couldn't find one for this situation. I tried changing the `message.mentions.users.first()` to `message.mentions.members.first()` but it showed the same error.

Comment: try ` const winner = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member`

Comment: `let winner = message.author` returns a User. And users don't have roles property.

Comment: oh ok let me try that. I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) and only `GuildMember`s have roles. You should use [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) instead that returns the author of the message as a `GuildMember`, so you can use its `roles` property.

You could also simplify that if else statement using an OR operator. If there is no member mentioned the value of `winner` will be the author of the message:

```js
execute(message, args) {
  const winner = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;
  let time = 0;

  // ...
```