# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')

Tags: discord, discord.js, roles, member

it said "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')"
what i can do? and i did a mistake in the code?

this is my code

```js
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'cutem',
    execute(client, message, args) {
      let member = message.author;
      member.roles.cache.has('989342982224355409');
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply("send what you want")
    
        let channel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.channel;
        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setImage(args[0])
        .setColor("GREYPLE")
        channel.send(`@here by : <@${message.author.id}>` )
        channel.send({embeds: [embed]})

     
   
    }
}
```

Comment: `message.author` returns a global Discord user, which does not have roles. Use `message.member` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431025/discord-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-cache-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=member) returns a global [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User) object which doesn't have any `roles` property, hence the error. What you actually need is a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember) which does have all the properties you need. So to get the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember) details of the user, all you have to do is, change the part where you declare the `member` variable from this:

```js
let member = message.author
```

to this:

```js
let member = message.member
```