# Verification system in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, roles

Basically when I do console.log(message.author.roles) it just says its undefined and from there im lost please help me

```js
const roleId = config.verify.roleId // 997167483473629324
const channelId = config.verify.channelId // 997167450024067194
const user = message.author
if (message.channel.id === channelId) {
    if (!user.roles.cache.has(roleId)) { // "roles" is undefined??
        message.reply({ embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('RED').setTitle('Verification').setDescription('Please wait.')] })
        setTimeout(() => {
            user.roles.add(roleId) // would probably be the same error here
        }, 1500)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord user roles are undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431025/discord-user-roles-are-undefined-typeerror-cannot-read-property-cache-of-unde)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author), you get a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User) object which represents the global user. Instead, to access the `roles` property, you need to use a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) object which represents a user in a guild. So, all you have to do to check all the roles a member has is by using one of these two methods:

- Fetching the member: If you want to fetch the member, you can get the user id by using [`message.author.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id) and then, fetch it from the guild. An example:

```js
const userId = message.author.id
const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(userId) // or await message.guild.members.fetch(userId)
console.log(member.roles)
```

- `message.member`: A much easier way is by using this method. By using this, you automatically get the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) details of the user who posted this message. An example:

```js
const member = message.member
console.log(member.roles)
```