# Getting roles of mentioned user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Working on a marriage system for my Discord bot but I am struggling to find out of a user has the "married" role already.

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: "marry",
    aliases: ['m'],
    description: "marry someone",


    async run(client, message, args) {

        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.get(args[0]);
        let marriedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Married");
        let singleRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Single");

        let proposerID = message.author.id;
        let proposerName = message.author.username;
        if (user.roles.cache.some(marriedRole)) {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`Sorry **${user.tag}**, is already married!`);
            let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
        }
        if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Single')) {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`**${user.username}**, **${message.author.username}** is asking for your hand in marriage, would you like to accept?`);
            let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
            messageEmbed.react('✅');
            messageEmbed.react('❌');
        }
        if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Married')) {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`Sorry **${message.author.username}**, but you are already married!`);
            let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
        }

        }
}
```

I keep getting the error

> if (user.roles.cache.some(marriedRole)) {
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord user roles are undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431025/discord-user-roles-are-undefined-typeerror-cannot-read-property-cache-of-unde)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`message.mentions.users.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users), you are getting a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object in return which doesn't have the [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) property. Instead, you need the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object. To get it, all you have to do is change the part where you declare the `user` variable to:

```js
const user = message.mentions.members.first() || client.users.get(args[0]);
```

**Answer from Zsolt Meszaros**
Since, if there is no mention in the message, `message.mentions.members.first()`, so keep that in mind. `client.users.get(args[0])` would also just get a `User` object, so instead of using that, you can use this:

```js
const user = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

Comment: Ah, it's definitely a duplicate and your answer won't work if there is no member mentioned. If someone passes an ID, you'll still receive a `User`. You should replace `client.users.get(args[0])` with `message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])`.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly. Thanks :)